# Sublime 3 with Arara

Tags: arara, sublime-text

I would like to use Sublime 3 for my LaTeX work, however I'm having some difficulty getting arara working as part of the build. I have TexLive installed so I have the arara binaries available (used them with TexStudio), and I don't mind about which LaTeX plugin I use (LaTeXing, LaTeXTools, LaTeXSQ), I'd just like arara working for glossaries.

Here is the snippet I'd like to compile as a test

```
% arara: pdflatex: { draft: true }
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true }    
% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: true } 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

% abbreviations:
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}

% nomenclature:
\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
  name = $a$ ,
  description = The number of angels per unit area,
}
\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
  name = $N$ ,
  description = The number of angels per needle point
}
\newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
  name = $A$ ,
  description = The area of the needle point
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\printglossary[title=Nomenclature]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

\gls{ny}, \gls{la} and \gls{un} are abbreviations whereas
\gls{angelsperarea}, \gls{numofangels} and \gls{areaofneedle} kare part of the
nomenclature
\gls{ny} \gls{ny} ;l

d
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure this is the best solution or if it'll cause me any problems in the future.

Using LaTeXing, I modified LaTeX.sublime-build.

Replaced

```
"cmd":
[
    "latexmk", "-f", "-quiet", "-pdf",
    "-synctex={synctex}",
    "-jobname={pdfname}",
    "-outdir={outdir}",
    "{file}"
],
```

with

```
"cmd":
[
    "arara",
    "{file}"
],
```

If someone more experienced with LaTeX can see something in this that will cause problems where I haven't noticed, please let me know.

edit: with this method I don't get any error output, and if there is an error it hangs on "Compiling..." and I have to exit pdflatex via task manager

Comment: You have to use some flags provided by `arara`. Run `arara` (alone) in the terminal and you will see options like `verbose`, `log`.

Comment: Possibly `"arara", "-v"` so the terminal will show the processing info.

Answer (score 2):

The solution with LaTeXTools is:

1. In Sublimetext 3 goto: *Preferences -> Package Settings -> LaTeXTools -> Settings -User*
2. Search "builder_settings"
3. Past the *scritp_commands*

   ```
   "builder_settings" : {
   // General settings:
   // See README or third-party documentation

   // (built-ins): true shows the log of each command in the output panel
   "display_log" : false,

   // Platform-specific settings:
   "osx" : {
       // See README or third-party documentation
   },

   "windows" : {
       // See README or third-party documentation
   },

   "linux" : {
       "script_commands": [
               "arara -v $file"
           ]
       }
   },
   ```
4. In Sublimetext 3 choose: *Tools -> Build System -> LaTeX*
5. In Sublimetext 3 choose: *Tools -> Build With -> LaTeX - Script Builder*